# How to pass variable into MagicImage

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am trying to use MagicImage to convert HEIC to JPEG, so my newFile.Data contain byte[] of image that was sent to server. So I am pretty sure that my code correct, but when I am sending image to server i.e to web it uploads in HEIC format but i need it in jpeg. So I am stuck here and can't figure out what i need to do

```
using (var image = new MagickImage(newFile.Data))
{
    // Sets the output format to jpeg
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;

    // Create byte array that contains a jpeg file
    byte[] data = image.ToByteArray();
}

var currentFiles = 
            _clientFileService.Value.GetFilesByClient(clientId).Where(x => x.ClientFileType == type).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

_clientFileService.Value.MultipleDelete(currentFiles, null);

_clientFileService
    .Value
    .AddFile(
    new ClientFile
    {
        Data = newFile.Data, // How can I pass MagickImage to newFile.Data
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to use the data of MagikImage in the fileService:

```
byte[] data = null;
using (var image = new MagickImage(newFile.Data))
{
    // Sets the output format to jpeg
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;

    // Create byte array that contains a jpeg file
    data = image.ToByteArray();
}

var currentFiles = _clientFileService.Value
    .GetFilesByClient(clientId)
    .Where(x => x.ClientFileType == type)
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();

_clientFileService.Value.MultipleDelete(currentFiles, null);

_clientFileService
    .Value
    .AddFile(new ClientFile
    {
        Data = data 
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
    });
```